Redirecionar a leitura para um arquivo input.txt
Eu estou tentando fazer o redirecionamento da leitura para um arquivo de texto, já tentei usar o comando java Main < input.txt, mas recebo apenas o erro  Operador '<' reservado para uso futuro. no terminal do Windows 11. Um pouco de contexto: estou fazendo exercícios no Beecrowd/URI Online Judge e queria efetuar a leitura a partir de um arquivo input.txt.
A seguir o código que uso para fazer a leitura.
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Main {
  public static LinkedList<String> readFromStdin() {
    LinkedList<String> total = new LinkedList<String>();

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
      total.add(sc.nextLine());
    }
    sc.close();

    return total;
  }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      LinkedList<String> linhas = readFromStdin();
      for (String l : linhas) {
        System.out.println(l);
      }
    }

}


Há alguma forma de redirecionar a leitura de um Scanner(System.in) para um arquivo de texto?

Sugiro que você use o BufferedReader para isto:
FileReader in = new FileReader("test.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);

String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
in.close();

Mas caso realmente queiras usar o Scanner (faltou no teu caso passar o objeto File para o construtor do Scanner):
    File file = new File("test.txt");
    input = new Scanner(file);

    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    input.close();


Encontrei o comando para rodar: cmd /c --% java Main < ./test.txt
